# Get the value from an appended selector option using JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value from an appended selector with a JQuery function. The function works well with the main element, that was not appended, but does nothing with the appended ones.

My code:

```
<div id="mainSeparator">
      <div id="newLayer" class="newLayer">        
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control mySelector" id="selector">
              <option hidden disabled selected value>Select an option</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newDiv"></div>
      </div>      
    </div>
```

The function I'm using now for get the values:

```
$(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function () {
      var str = "";
      $('.mySelector option:selected').each(function () {
        str += $( this ).text();
        $('.newDiv').text(str);
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you always target `$('.mySelector option:selected')`. This will only ever look at the first instance of the `.mySelector` element in the DOM.

From the context of the logic it appears that you want to look at the selected options *within* the `select` that raised the `change` event. As such you need to use `this` and `find()`. Also note that it would make more sense to update `.newDiv` once after the loop completes:

```
$(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function () {
  var str = "";
  $(this).find('option:selected').each(function () {
    str += $(this).text();
  });
  $('.newDiv').text(str);
});
```

The logic could also be made more slightly succinct by using `map()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '.mySelector', function () {
  var str = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join('');
  $('.newDiv').text(str);
});
```

Comment: Sadly the first example does not worked, it behaves the same way that the original example I posted. The second  example does not work either, but throws an error: `$(...).find(...).map(...).join is not a function`. I tought that the .on() function are able to access all the appended elements, I even used other times for do something similar, but without the `<select>` element.

Comment: Apologies, I missed `get()` from the second example. `on()` functions do not intrinsically pick up all appended elements, you specifically need to use the delegated signature of the method, which you are so that's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the `.on()` tip. Now it's not showing a error anymore, but its not work either. Maybe it's because of the `$('.newDiv').text(str);`? Should I change this part too? Tried to change the method to edit the unique ID of the element, no success either.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle link for a more visual understanding on what is happening. I see that you example works there, so there something else in my code that is causing this situation. But there is still some problem, when I change the selector in one layer, I don't want that the values of other layers changed, is this possible?

Comment: I going to give you right answer to this question and going to open another one more detailed with this new problem. Thank you so far.